# why temp file doesn't echo its data its echo file path

Tags: php

I want to store a random key for every user in temp file . But what is the problem in my code it's echo the file path and can't create a temp file .

```
<?php
function random_string($length) {
    $key = '';
    $keys = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'));

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];
    }

    return $key;
}

$data = random_string(50);

$filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'prefix');
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

call this file by:

```
<?php
$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), '');
echo $temp_file;
?>
```

result is something like this:`/tmp/LnRFYu`
/tmp dir is empty haven't create anything .
what is the problem on my code

Comment: are you sure you want to use the system temp dir? whats this key for?

Comment: I want to create a token for active a button . When user come it say enter your token and have 'get token' button.users need to go token.php page for get his/her token.so i need a temporary file for store token and it call from token.php page.How can it possible . Please help me.

Comment: couldent you just use a session?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the temp file creation code, so I don't really see what you are asking. I'm assuming you want to be able to view the contents of a specific temp file that has been created.

To do that your can use file_get_contents($file_name);

Like so

```
$contents = file_get_contents(sys_get_temp_dir() . 'temp_file_name.tmp');
echo $contents;
```

Comment: It's say Warning: file_get_contents(/tmptemp_file_name.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u325188346/public_html/zc.php on line 36

Comment: Add slash sys_get_temp_dir() . '/temp_file_name.tmp'